# Read data from hyperterminal in C (ASCII )

Tags: c, data-structures, serial-port, embedded, structure

I need a help to develop a C code to read data from terminal(terminal accepts only ASCII) and to convert this ascii to integer. Do you know or where to find the information or any suggestion?
The terminal should accept a input from the user (Example : new temperature value) and convert into integer. This integer value will be transferred across the interface (RS232 interface) to the memory.

example : the message structure -

```
struct memoryTag1;
typedef struct memoryTag1{
char a[10]= {'+','0','2','6','.','5','E','A','\r'}; // first five bits is the new temperature value (+26.5), two bits (euipment name- EA), carriage reurn.
char b[10]= {'-','0','2','4','.','5','E','B','\r'};
char c[8]= {'+','0','2','0','E','C','\r'};
}Memory1;
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: The actual reading very much depends on your platform. the value conversion is fairly trivial. As a side note, you seem to be confusing bits and bytes.

Comment: What is wrong with the answers you've already received? Please stop re-posting almost exactly the same question over and over, and ignoring the answers.

Comment: I will correct that message structure but how the user enters a new temperature value which matches with  the message structure. later how it will transfered over a serial interface ??

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert to an integer when the input data has a decimal point?

Comment: @unwind This question is about reading, that one was about writing (perhaps - not entirely clear).

Comment: It is not clear where the program resides. Are you writing a Windows program which communicates with an embedded device, or are you writing an embedded program communicating with a PC? Also, what kind of memory are you referring to? On-chip memory on a microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperterminal is an application not a device, you cannot "read data from Hyperterminal", it reads data from a serial port.  What you need to ask is how to read data from a serial port.

On most platforms you can read it via the standard stream I/O functions - `fopen`, `fread`, `fscanf` for example, though these may not give the control or flexibility you require; in which case you will need to use lower level OS API calls.

At its simplest in Windows you could do:

```
double data;
char equip[16] ;
FILE* portfp = 0 ;

system( "mode com1: baud=9600 parity=n data=8 stop=1" ) ;

portfp = fopen( "com1:", "r" ) ;
if( portfp != 0 )
{
    fscanf( portfp, "%f%s", &data, equip ) ;
    fclose(portfp ) ;
}
```

The Win32 API has lower level and [more comprehensive set of functions for serial I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx), but is not so straightforward.  The .NET framework has a serial I/O class that is far simpler to use than Win32, but you cannot use that in C - you'll need C# or C++/CLI.

Comment: if the user want to enter a temperature value over the terminal (terminal accepts only ASCII) then how to go about it ??

Comment: @user1647229 You have repeated yourself, and it makes no more sense the second time.  If the input is `"+026.5EA"`, then the code above will end up with `data=26.5` and `equip = "EA"`.  If that is not the answer you expected, then consider your question in that context and improve it, because it is unclear.